# POST request is returning response success but is not posting the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am making a POST request to the MOXTRA API and it should return me the following response :

```
{

"data":

{

"id": user_id, //some user id
"revision": 5,
"name": "My First Binder",
"created_time": 1402384947587,
"updated_time": 1402384947587
},

"code": "RESPONSE_SUCCESS"
}
```

And I am making this POST request using Java Script

```
var d = 

    {
      'name': 'My First Binder'
    };

var bind = JSON.stringify(d);

$.post('https://api.moxtra.com/user_id/binders?access_token=' + access_token+ '&callback=?', bind, function(response) {

  alert( response.data.id);

},'json');
    })
```

But the alert that i get for alert(response.data.id) is "undefined"
and the alert if i write alert(response.code) is  "RESPONSE_SUCCESS"

What is wrong with the above code , how am i getting a response success and getting undefined at the same time

Comment: have you tried alerting/consoling out the complete response object?

Comment: `...and it should return...`: check the returned value first

Comment: Check what is returned in some kind of firebug, dev console of Google Chrome etc.

Comment: I checked it , when i add JSONP , it is making a GET request rather than a POST request . Is there anyway to work around this